# Selecting a record from a mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to select data from my db, but instead of getting a certain field I get "".
My table name is locations and it's look like this:

id - int,
location - varchar and time - timestamp.

I would like to select the last location based on the time, here is my code:

```
this.select = this.conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT location FROM locations ORDER BY time DESC Limit 1");
result.next();
System.out.println(result.getString(1));
```

I remind you the output is "";

Comment: What do you get if you select more than one row? What if you run the select through the mysql client?

Comment: have you tried result.getString("location")?

Comment: @travega thank you! post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the column in your resultSet you can use:

```
result.getString("location");
```

Answer (score 0):

did u try ?

```
System.out.println(result.getString(0));
```

Comment: As you can see in the Java API for ResultSet.getString, the columnindex is one based and not zero based!

Comment: thx, im still trying 2 understand the system. if i only answered wht im 100% sure of then i guess i will hv 2 wait for clarifications on Hello World b4 i cud answer anything. sleuths here are farout.. but i have got a little patient now n thankfully a little enlightened about stackoverflow now and just learned about the comment box 2. i will b careful from next time.